# Length of Strings in a Dataframe

Tags: string, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column with the length of a comment made by someone:

```
message['TextLength'] = message['MessageContent'].apply(len)
```

Annoyingly, and interesting, this is a task I've performed quite a lot; sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. The error thrown when it doesn't work:

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

The error is obvious; you can't use len() on floats.  However, my dataframe contains text messages, strings, so I'm a little confused.

```
message dataframe:

Label                 MessageContent

ham   Go until jurong point, crazy.. 

ham   Ok lar... Joking wif u oni... 

spam  Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup fina... 

ham   U dun say so early hor... U c already then say... 

ham   Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives aro...
```

If anyone has a way of getting round this, or know more about why this error comes about, it would be great

Comment: Just change the type to string...ie `message['MessageContent'].astype(str).apply(len)`

Comment: @Onyambu; worked, cheers for that